# How to write regular expression to validate character in special places?

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I need to validate time field in the textbox. I used this regular expression.

```
   var reg_exp = /^([0-9\:]*)$/;
```

But it allows add : any place in the text box. How to make it to add : only in the third place of the text.
 Ex: 11**:**34

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
^\d{2}:\d{2}$
```

instead which matches two digits, then a colon and another two digits.

Comment: var reg_exp = /^\d{2}:\d{2}$/;
        if(!reg_exp.test(time) ){
            return "time should contain only numbers";   
        }  I use this code.always regex return false.

Comment: ok dr, it is working correctly. previously it didn't work because of I called validate function onkeyup() event.

Answer (score 1):

In order to verify that the time is beween `00:00` and `23:59` you could use:

```
/^(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-3]):(?:[0-5][0-9])$/
```